# Cannot import when using Eclipse and Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, import, gradle

I am working on a java project which uses Gradle to build. I wanted to use the Eclipse WindowBuilder to help with the GUI work, so I used the Gradle Eclipse plugin, generated the Eclipse files, and imported it into Eclipse.

The problem is that none of my imports are resolving.  The project builds fine using Gradle, but Eclipse can't import anything for my project.  How do I solve this?

I don't know which files to include to help debug this, so if something might help let me know and I will include it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: Here is my build.gradle file:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}


buildscript {
    def rosMavenPath = "$System.env.ROS_MAVEN_PATH".split(':').collect { 'file://' + it }
    def rosMavenRepository = "$System.env.ROS_MAVEN_REPOSITORY"
    repositories {
        rosMavenPath.each { p ->
            maven {
                url p
            }
        }
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url rosMavenRepository
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.ros.rosjava_bootstrap', name: 'gradle_plugins', version: '[0.1,0.2)'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'catkin'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'


allprojects {
    /*
      A github url provides a good standard unique name for your project
      Example below, but you may wish to switch to your own unique url.
    */
    group 'com.github.rosjava.gui_test'
    version = project.catkin.pkg.version
}

subprojects {
    /*
      See https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap (look for gradle_plugins)
      to see what is going on under the hood.
    */
    apply plugin: 'ros-java'
}
```

Comment: Providing your build.gradle could help.

Comment: Provided. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: I don't know how, but I seem to have fixed it. I don't know how I fixed it though =/

Comment: Glad to hear it's 'fixed'..